# Show that $|K_{2,5}|=60.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

For a positive integer $n\ge 4$ and a prime number $p\le n$,let $U_{p,n}$ denote the union of all Sylow $p$ subgroups of $A_n$ .Also let $K_{p,n}$ denote the subgroup of $A_n$ generated by $U_{p,n}$ and let $|K_{p,n}|$ denote the order of $K_{p,n}$.

Show that $|K_{2,4}|=4$ and $|K_{2,5}|=60.$

**My try**:Number of Sylow $2$ subgroups of $A_4=1+2k=n_2|3 \implies n_2=1,3$ .$A_4$ has only one Sylow $2$ subgroup of order $4$ i.e. $\{e,(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}\implies |U_{2,4}|=4\implies |K_{2,4}|=4$.

But I am unable to solve the problem in case of $A_5$ .Please give some hints

Comment: $K_{p,n}$ is a normal subgroup of $A_n$, which is simple for $n \ge 5$.

Comment: How do you claim that $K_{p,n}$ is normal in $A_5$ ;Please explain.

Comment: It is characteristic, which is a stronger property than normality. Sometimes it is easier to prove a stronger property!

Comment: Why is it characteristic ?Please explain

Comment: It is normal, since all Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate, it is characteristic since all $p$-elements remain $p$-elements under an automorphism.

Comment: Every element of $K_{p,n}$ is a product of elements of some Sylow subgroup of $A_n$, and so is its image under an automorphism of $A_n$ (since the Sylow subgroups are conjugate). This makes $K_{p,n}$ a normal subgroup of $A_n$. Since $A_n$ is simple $K_{p,n}$ is either the trivial identity subgroup of $A_n$ (clearly not the case) either the whole of $A_n itsellf.